# SQL - How to Count custom Created Error Codes

Tags: mysql, sql-server, count

Our software generates error codes that we built into it, these codes are saved under a column in a SQL database. The goal is to build a query to run and count how many times each error appeared in the past 30 days and set each result to a customer variable that is returned.

---

```
set @error#1 = (@error#1 + 1) where Errors like '%E001%' and CreatedDate > DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
print("There were" + @policyfail#1 + "Error#1's in the past month.")
```

---

So to explain the thoughts above you should take the custom variable @error#1 and add 1 to it for each time it sees that error code (E001) from within a specified time frame.

All errors get inserted under a unique code attached to the message I.E. "E001 - Error connecting to SQL database." and so we are trying to query for the code portion at the beginning ("E001")

We are also trying to be able to repeat this smaller query for all of the errors that we have (we have a few hundred) in a larger query that will return the number of occurrences of every existing error in a single script.

---

The problem we have is that each action of the software saves the errors under a single string until that user signs off. So one user for a day would have multiple errors saved as a single string to a single cell in a table.

---

The results from the larger query should essentially by a few hundred lines that displays the number of every error within the past month that looks something like this:

```
"There were 15000 Error#1's in the past month."

"There were 20000 Error#2's in the past month."

"There were 10000 Error#3's in the past month."
```

---

The above results would then continue until it gets through every error.

Comment: Are you storing these error codes in a table in SQL Server? If so, please post the table structure and sample of data.

Comment: Drop one of the database tags, as there are subtle differences between MySQL and SQL-Server and only the one that is relevant to the question should be present.

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a query you could do it using something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Count], SUBSTRING([Errors], 1, 4) AS [ErrorCode]
FROM [MyTableName]
WHERE SUBSTRING([Errors], 1, 4) LIKE 'E[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
   AND [CreatedDate] > DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())
GROUP BY SUBSTRING([Errors], 1, 4)
```

If you want it in text form, the iterate through that with a cursor and use PRINT statements for each row.